# Efficient Database Multiple Model Create Operation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model named (Sale) but this model is associated with another model called (ItemSold), I am trying to create a Sale record and 30 itemSold record at once in the create action for the sales controller. I was considering taking such operations to the background worker, Would performing the operation in the sale controller be an inefficient approach or should i just move the operation to a background worker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) gem. With `activerecord-import`, you can do this with only two queries. One for creating the sale record and another to bulk insert the 30 ItemSold records all at once. This way you won't have a performance issue and can do the operation in the controller instead of a background job.